# Perforce P4V Fetch Indicator

Tags: perforce, p4v

Does p4v indicate somewhere that there is content to be fetched or alternatively, a way to preview what would be fetched (Outside of manually comparing history against the remote depot)?

Edit: I should have mentioned I'm using DVCS.

Comment: There's [a bunch of status icons](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/#P4V/using.icons.html%3FTocPath%3DUsing%2520P4V%7C_____5).  Do any of those fit the bill?

Comment: I'm using DVCS so unfortunately I don't believe they apply in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working directly against a shared server, the UI automatically refreshes with file badges that show you whether there are new revisions you can sync, and there's a dashboard view that'll show you that information at the global changelist level.

If you're using the DVCS mode, the UI support is a little more bare-bones and generally operates against your local server in isolation.  You might want to use the `p4 fetch -n` command from the terminal, which will tell you whether you're up to date and whether there are any conflicts with the remote server.

Comment: Thanks, p4 fetch -n is the command line equivalent to one of the options I'm looking for in p4v (I am using DVCS mode). Do you know if there is a GUI equivalent?

Comment: I doubt it -- my understanding is that the GUI support for p4 DVCS is pretty minimal.

Comment: Alright, I'll make do with the command line for this for now. Thanks.